# Codeiginiter config database file

Tags: codeigniter

Am wondering given the codeigniter `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, can I load different config files for each type of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`?

For example if the url is localhost, run `config_localhost` instead, if url is live, run `config_live`. Similarly for the database.php as well.

What I have so far is do a check in the respective files and a switch loop to check the server name.

```
     switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {      
          case KH_SERVER_NAME:  // development server   
              $config['base_url']    = 'localhost';     
              break;

          default:  // live server 
            $config['base_url']    ="http://www.domain.com";    
             break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do stuff like this. I would suggest putting something like this into your root `index.php` so that it gets set right at the start:

```php
  switch( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] )
  {
    case 'www.domainname.com':
      define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
    break;
    case 'dev.domainname.com':
      define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
    break;
    case 'test.localhost':
    case 'www.test.localhost':
      define('ENVIRONMENT', 'local');
    break;
  }
```

This defines a variable called `ENVIRONMENT` that you can then use throughout your config files (and application, if you want) - that way, rather than testing against a $_SERVER variable, you can just do something like:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
  case 'local':
  case 'development':
    $config['base_url'] = 'localhost';
  break;

  case 'production':
    $config['base_url']    ="http://www.domain.com";
  break;
}
```

and other handy things like:

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
  case 'local':
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
  break;

  case 'development':
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
  break;

  case 'production':
    error_reporting(0);
  break;
}
```

This can also be used in the main application, for example to decide if you want to output analytics tracking code or not in a view - something that you generally only want to be output in production - eg:

```
  <? if(ENVIRONMENT == 'production'): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-Y']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
    </script>
  <? endif ?>
```